# Making a reset placed objects button in Flash (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a drag and drop project where everytime I click on a movieclip a clone is made that can be dragged. I would like to know how to make a button that can reset/remove the clones when the button is pressed.

This is what I got so far:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var latestClone:MovieClip;

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPlusPressed);

function onPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{

latestClone = new Plus();

latestClone.x = event.stageX;
latestClone.y = event.stageY;

addChild(latestClone);

latestClone.startDrag();

latestClone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, latestClone.startDrag);

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageReleased);

function onStageReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{

if(latestClone != null){

    latestClone.stopDrag();

}
}
```

Comment: look up `removeChildAt` to  remove recently added "clone". Use a `For Loop` to remove multiple clones at once. Best you addChild everything into a container MovieClip then you can run the loop against that `container_MC.removeChildAt( );` also easier to check how many clones that MovieClip contains etc...

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your clones in an array, and loop over the array and do a `removeChild` on each item in the array. So:

```
var items:Array = new Array();
....
addChild(latestClone);
items.push(latestClone); 
....
var resetButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
//set your button properties here
resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onResetClicked);
addChild(resetButton);

function onResetClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    reset();
}
function reset():void
{
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
    {     
         removeChild(items[i]);
         items[i] = null;
    }
    items = new Array();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gurtej, but I don't know how to use what you posted to make a button that can reset the clones that have been dragged on stage. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've posted the actual logic, create a new button and call the reset function that I posted from the mouse click listener of the button.

Comment: Hi, I've added some sample code as to how to create the button and add a listener to it. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I know how to create a button, and I tried to follow your instructions but I still can't get the button to work.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? are you seeing your button? Are you not able to click it? Is there any movieclip overlapping the button? You'll have to be more specific on the issue.

Comment: The latest error I got was: Access of undefined property items. I already made a movieclip button with the instance: resetButton

Comment: And this is what I have in the actionscript panel for the button: resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onResetClicked);

function onResetClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    reset();
}
function reset():void
{
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
    {     
         removeChild[i];
         items[i] = null;
    }
    items = new Array();
}

Comment: see my updated code. You must have all your code in the same actions panel. You cannot declare an array in some other actions panel and use it in another one. I would recommend write your code on the actual frame and  not inside the actions for the button

Comment: All the code seems to be in the right place and on the frame. I get this error when not removing the simplebutton var: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@3b010121 to flash.display.SimpleButton.
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline()

Comment: and this error when removing it: TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: You are trying to convert a movie clip to a button, thats the first error. Please update your entire code above. Why are your trying to remove the button?

Comment: I meant I got the error when removing the simplebutton var in the actions, and im using a movieclip as a button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question by testing several possibilities with the code that was posted + searching other questions.

This is the code that worked:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var latestClone:MovieClip;

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPlusPressed);

function onPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{

latestClone = new Plus();

latestClone.x = event.stageX;
latestClone.y = event.stageY;

addChild(latestClone);

latestClone.startDrag();

latestClone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClonedPlusPressed);

}

function onClonedPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void{


latestClone = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);


latestClone.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageReleased);

function onStageReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{

if(latestClone != null){

latestClone.stopDrag();
items.push(latestClone); 
}
}



resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);



function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{



}

var items:Array = new Array();






resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onResetClicked);
addChild(resetButton);

function onResetClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
reset();
}
function reset():void
{
for (var i:uint = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
{        items[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClonedPlusPressed);
     if(items[i].parent) items[i].parent.removeChild(items[i]);
      items[i] = null;
}
items = new Array()



}
```

Comment: You need one more line in your reset function to remove the event listener from your clone, otherwise the clone object will stay in the memory forever and will be not garbage collected:  items[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClonedPlusPressed);

Answer (score 0):

just declare container variable like so:

```
var clone_container:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

put all clones inside,than u can clear it up very easely:

```
while(clone_container.numChildren > 0){
    clone_container.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

that's all..

Answer (score 0):

you most add an array and push object into this,

your solution:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
var latestClone:MovieClip;
plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPlusPressed);
var plusArray:Array = new Array();

resetbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,resetFunc);
function resetFunc(e:Event)
{
    for (var i=0; i<plusArray.length; i++)
    {
        removeChild(plusArray[i]);
    }
    plusArray = new Array()
}

function onPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    latestClone = new Plus();

    latestClone.x = event.stageX;
    latestClone.y = event.stageY;

    plusArray.push(latestClone);
    addChild(plusArray[plusArray.length-1]);
    plusArray[plusArray.length - 1].startDrag();
    plusArray[plusArray.length - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, plusArray[plusArray.length-1].startDrag);

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageReleased);

function onStageReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (latestClone != null)
    {

        latestClone.stopDrag();

    }
}
```

**Good luck**